# [openni_tracker] InitFromXml failed: Can't create any node of the requested type!

Tags: kinect, openni, openi-tracker, openni-kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to use the openni_tracker node in the openni_kinect stack but when I try and run it I get the following error message:

> InitFromXml failed: Can't create any node of the requested type!

I'm using ros-diamondback and I'm trying to use openni_tracker with the kinect. This is really frustrating because I already had it working. Any help on why I'm getting this error would be appreciated.

Also, because openni_tracker doesn't display a view of the camera's image I was wondering if there was an easily accessible node that could display the skeleton tracking image tracker is based on.

Thanks

Anthony

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9737/%5Bopenni_tracker%5D-initfromxml-failed:-can%27t-create-any-node-of-the-requested-type!/) by [soilwoker](https://answers.ros.org/users/429/soilwoker/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2011-04-14

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to register the license key for the dev modules.

"sudo niLicense -l 0KOIk2JeIBYClPWVnMoRKn5cdY4="

Steven

---

Originally posted by [s_martin](https://answers.ros.org/users/842/s_martin/) with karma: 26 on 2011-07-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2011-11-18**:
The command itself worked for my turtlebot/Ubuntu, with exactly the same values without double-quotation, showing PrimeSense being associated with the key. However I still get the same error.

**Comment by [bunower](https://answers.ros.org/users/479/bunower/) on 2011-07-19**:
it doesnt work! And if i try "sudo niLicense -r Primesense 0KOIk2JeIBYClPWVnMoRKn5cdY4=" i get the error : "Failed: Failed to write to the file!"

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using ROS Hydro on Ubuntu 12.04 with a Microsoft Kinect.  From top to bottom, this is what worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-<ros_distro>-openni-camera
sudo apt-get install ros-<ros_distro>-openni-launch
sudo apt-get install ros-<ros_distro>-openni-tracker
```

Go to [this Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com/sh/jsygeyx8dwa49w6/AAA-XmOWcz9svJBZQ_VKMS3ha) from isura (Thanks) and download `NITE-Bin-Linux-x64-v1.5.2.23.tar.zip`.
Extract the zip and tar into a temporary folder (i.e., ~/tmp).

```
cd ~/tmp/NITE-Bin-Dev-Linux-x64-v1.5.2.23/
sudo ./install.sh
```

Ensure your Microsoft Kinect is properly connected, then run:

```
roslaunch openni_launch openni_launch camera:=openni
```

In a separate terminal window run:

```
rosrun openni_tracker openni_tracker
```

In another terminal window run:

```
rosrun rviz rviz
```

In Rviz, change Global Options > Fixed Frame to openni_depth_optical_frame.

"Add" the visualization (bottom left) PointCloud2.

Change PointCloud2 >Topic to /openni/depth_registered/points (but whatever you pick works).

"Add" the visualization (bottom left) TF.

Stand in front of the Microsoft Kinect and make the "Psi Pose".  Axes should appear on all your joints.

I hope this helps you.  There are a lot of different versions of NITE out there and this is the one that happened to work for me.

---

Originally posted by [sealguy77](https://answers.ros.org/users/20929/sealguy77/) with karma: 323 on 2015-02-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [adelleodel](https://answers.ros.org/users/24939/adelleodel/) on 2016-02-08**:
it still have respond:

```
[ERROR] [1454926421.236391161]: NITE is likely missing: Please install NITE >= 1.5.2.21. Check the readme for download information. Error Info: User generator failed: Can't create any node of the requested type!
```

HELP!!

**Comment by [张京林](https://answers.ros.org/users/19842/%E5%BC%A0%E4%BA%AC%E6%9E%97/) on 2016-11-22**:
I also meet the problem:

```
 NITE is likely missing: Please install NITE >= 1.5.2.21.
```

But when I remove and reinstall the NITE and Sensor and change the usb port by many times, it worked. I just run two commands:

```
roscore  
rosrun openni_tracker openni_tracker
```